# How to go from string to ToDictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm not completely clear on lambda expressions and I'm trying to use them to convert the following string into a dictionary where the item before the equals sign is the key, and the item after the equals sign is the value.

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

string stringOfKeyValuePairs = "Item1=value1 Item2=value2 Item3=value3 Item4=value4"
```

Is there a way to split the string and use the ToDictionary() method to get the results I want?

Thank you

**Edit:** I made the string simpler as I can already parse the string down to what I want and the complex version adds no value to the information I am seeking.

Comment: How are the key-value pairs delimited? By Space? Can you have spaces within the values?

Comment: I hope you're using an XML/HTML parser to extract the values from the raw string.

Comment: There are probably better options for learning about lambdas than this exercise..

Comment: Sorry, the complexity of the string takes away from my question, I've edited it down to the bare bones of what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: What do you want to happen when you have duplicate item names? How do you represent values that include spaces and equal signs? If you think those won't happen, you need to explain what makes you think they won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are keen on doing this in LINQ, you can do a couple of `Split`s and a `ToDictionary`, but it feels pretty fragile. I don't know if there will never be spaces, if you will always have unique `Key`s, etc. If that's not an issue, something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string stringOfKeyValuePairs = "Item1=value1 Item2=value2 Item3=value3 Item4=value4";
        
        var myDictionary = stringOfKeyValuePairs.Split(' ')
            .Select(i => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(i.Split('=')[0],i.Split('=')[1]))
            .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.Value);
        
        myDictionary.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"KEY: {x.Key} VALUE: {x.Value}"));
    }
}
```

see:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uhekuv

Output:

```
KEY: Item1 VALUE: value1
KEY: Item2 VALUE: value2
KEY: Item3 VALUE: value3
KEY: Item4 VALUE: value4
```

Answer (score -1):

You can remove corner brackets and split the string by some delimieter (looks like in your case it will be '='). Then you can use each even index element of returned array as a key and odd as a value and add it to the dictionary.
Also you should remove questes before adding dictionary value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't let downvotes discourage you from participating. You can always [edit] a post to add details or correct mistakes.